# Find an algorithm to inverse quickly a large matrix of symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, matrix, gpu, symbolic-math, matrix-inverse

I have to solve the equality between 2 matrixes 12x12 containing a lot of symbolic variables and with which I perform inversion of matrix. There is only one unknown called "`SIGMA_O`".

My system is solved fastly when I take for example 2 matrices 2x2, the inversion is pretty direct.

Now, with the case of 2 matrixes 12x12, I need before actually to inverse a 31x31 matrix of symbolic variables (I marginalize after), since inversion takes a lot of time.

I would like to benefit from my GPU NVIDIA QUADRO RTX 6000 to achieve this inversion faster but the GPU optimization is not supported currently for Symbolic arrays.

Below the script where you will find the line of inversion :

```
COV_ALL = inv(FISH_SYM)
```

and the entire code :

```
clear;
clc;
format long;
% 2 Fisher Matrixes symbolic : FISH_GCsp_SYM, : 1 cosmo params + 1 bias spectro put for common
%                              FISH_XC_SYM : 1 cosmo params + 2 bias photo correlated
% GCsp Fisher : 7 param cosmo and 5 bias spectro which will be summed
FISH_GCsp_SYM = sym('sp_', [17,17], 'positive');
% Force symmetry for GCsp
FISH_GCsp_SYM = tril(FISH_GCsp_SYM.') + triu(FISH_GCsp_SYM,1)
% GCph Fisher : 7 param cosmo + 3 I.A + 11 bias photo correlated 
FISH_XC_SYM = sym('xc_', [21,21], 'positive');
% Force symmetry for GCph
FISH_XC_SYM = tril(FISH_XC_SYM.') + triu(FISH_XC_SYM,1)
% Brutal Common Bias : sum of 7 cosmo param ans 5 bias spectro : FISH_ALL1 = first left matrix
FISH_ALL1 = sym('xc_', [12,12], 'positive');
% Sum cosmo
FISH_ALL1(1:7,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,1:7) + FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,1:7);
% Brutal sum of bias
FISH_ALL1(7:12,7:12) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:12,7:12) + FISH_XC_SYM(15:20,15:20);
% Adding new observable "O" terms
FISH_O_SYM = sym('o_', [2,2], 'positive');
% Definition of sigma_o
SIGMA_O = sym('sigma_o', 'positive');
FISH_O_SYM = 1/(SIGMA_O*SIGMA_O) * FISH_O_SYM
% Force symmetry
FISH_O_SYM = (tril(FISH_O_SYM.') + triu(FISH_O_SYM,1))
FISH_O_SYM
%FISH_SYM = sym('xc_', [31,31], 'positive');
%FISH_BIG_GCsp = sym('sp_', [31,31], 'positive');
%FISH_BIG_XC = sym('xc_', [31,31], 'positive');
FISH_SYM = zeros(31,31,'sym');
FISH_BIG_GCsp = zeros(31,31,'sym');
FISH_BIG_XC = zeros(31,31,'sym');

% Block bias spectro + pshot and correlations;
FISH_BIG_GCsp(1:7,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,1:7);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(7:17,7:17) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:17,7:17);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(1:7,7:17) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,7:17);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(7:17,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:17,1:7);

% Block bias photo and correlations;
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,1:7);
FISH_BIG_XC(21:31,21:31) = FISH_XC_SYM(11:21,11:21);
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,21:31) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,11:21);
FISH_BIG_XC(21:31,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(11:21,1:7);

% Block I.A and correlations;
FISH_BIG_XC(18:20,18:20) = FISH_XC_SYM(8:10,8:10);
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,18:20) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,8:10);
FISH_BIG_XC(18:20,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(8:10,1:7);

% Final summation
FISH_SYM = FISH_BIG_GCsp + FISH_BIG_XC;

% Add O observable
FISH_SYM(6,6) = FISH_SYM(6,6) + FISH_O_SYM(1,1);
FISH_SYM(6,26) = FISH_SYM(6,26) + FISH_O_SYM(2,2);
FISH_SYM(26,6) = FISH_SYM(26,6) + FISH_O_SYM(1,2);
FISH_SYM(26,26) = FISH_SYM(26,26) + FISH_O_SYM(2,1);

% Force symmetry
FISH_SYM = (tril(FISH_SYM.') + triu(FISH_SYM,1))

% Marginalize FISH_SYM2 in order to get back a 2x2 matrix
% Invert to marginalyze : take a long long time 
COV_ALL = inv(FISH_SYM);
% Marginalize
COV_ALL([13:31],:) = [];
COV_ALL(:,[13:31]) = [];
FISH_ALL2 = inv(COV_ALL);
FISH_ALL1
FISH_ALL2
% Matricial equation to solve
eqn = FISH_ALL1 == FISH_ALL2;
% Solving : sigma_o unknown
[solx, parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, SIGMA_O, 'ReturnConditions', true);
solx
```

I think that I have to get "known methods" to inverse a matrix, in order to avoid to apply a raw inversion with **INV** Matlab's function.

Maybe this technique could be exploited by GPU. If not this is no bad, the most important is to find an algorithm of inversion of symbolic matrix that allows to gain in runtime.

What are the existing algorithms of inversion that I could potentially use?

### Update 1

Here is what I am doing in this script.

First, the system of equations is just an equality with 2 matrices 12x12. The first one is obtained quickly by removing columns/rows to get a first 12x12 matrix.

The second matrix is more difficult to get : I have to inverse a 31x31 matrix, then on the inverse matrix, I marginalize by removing all nuisance Moterms, that is to say, by removing columns/rows to get a 12x12 matrix and I reinverse this latter to finally have the second matrix equal to the first one described above.

### Update 2

I realized that it might possible to reduce the runtime, thanks to the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) : Indeed, we could write :

[image: Method od Schur]

I did the following modifications :

```
% Using Schur complement formula
D = FISH_SYM(13:31,13:31)
inv_D = inv(D)
% Apply formula of Schur complement
COV_ALL = FISH_SYM(1:12,1:12) - FISH_SYM(1:12,13:31)*inv_D*FISH_SYM(13:31,1:12)
FISH_ALL2 = inv(COV_ALL);
```

instead of "big" inversion with first inversion on 31x31 matrix:

```
COV_ALL = inv(FISH_SYM);
% Marginalize
COV_ALL([13:31],:) = [];
COV_ALL(:,[13:31]) = [];
FISH_ALL2 = inv(COV_ALL);
```

Do you think my modifications are right ?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your prior post? The same over-formatted edit was made to your last question.

Comment: @halfer . Sorry, I forgot to delete them. So, this current post is the right one.